# Want to get Coordinates of Webbrowser Mouse Hover,Click when Document is null

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

I want to add a functionality in Webbrowser control in subclass, so that i when mouse is (clicked,hover,mouse up etc) on webbrowser control, it raises a event like for all other controls.

I can found OnMouseClickEvent in Webbrowser Control because it is inherited from System.Windows.Form.Control but that is not working nor available for use in object.

How can i add this functionality and use the event, Can i use Pinvoke to get coordinates once i have access to this functionality.

I searched on Google but found no related help ,I tried to do it myself but due to little understanding ,i was not able to go further .Kindly help me in getting this functionality .

Answer (score 0):

You can use these guidelines if you want to go with JS. This js and functionality description could help you alot
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

If you are not using any server side events to be fired when mouse events happened this would be the best solution for your needs.